# Combining expressions

Tags: regex

How do I combine two or more regex expressions such that a match occurs only when both expressions are true. 
For instance I want to identify Text containing 6 digits (not beginning with a 5) within word boundaries i.e.

```
\b[0-46-9]\d{5}\b
```

but I want to exclude Text containing `000000`

```
^(?!.*000000).*$

abc234576c Match
abc534756c No Match
abc000000c No Match
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Would you mind formatting your question properly? As it stands, it's hard to read. Concerning your question, you might be looking for several lookarounds.

Comment: Try `\b[a-zA-Z]*(?!0{6})[0-46-9]\d{5}[a-zA-Z]*\b`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this regex pattern:

```
\b(?!.*000000)[^0-9]*[0-46-9]\d{5}[^0-9]*\b
```

This assumes that you are looking to match a six digit number possibly with non numbers both preceding and proceeding it.  It also ensures that the number is not `000000` and the number does not begin with `5`.

## Demo

Answer (score 0):

Your first regex miss one important point, \b is identifying contrast between a word character (digits included) and a non-word character.
When the whole text is needed, that should work:

```
[a-zA-Z]*[0-46-9]\d{5}[a-zA-Z]*
```

Combining it with your proper second expression, you would get:

```
[A-Za-z]*(?!0{6})[0-46-9]\d{5}[A-Za-z]*
```

You can view the results [here](https://regex101.com/r/Z4Tv9u/1).

Comment: Sorry @Tim Biegeleisen, didn't see your post before.

Comment: The only possible issue with `[A-Za-z]` is that it only matches letters and not non numbers.  But perhaps that it OK in this case.

Comment: You're right, just making me realizing I improperly assumed it was the case.